# PyCharm won't find pytz

Tags: python, pycharm

While I'm SURE `pytz` is installed in my virtualenv, as well as I'm SURE that my PyCharm's project is using the said virtualenv, the IDE is constantly complaining:

[image: No module named pytz in PyCharm]

And when I check in the virtualenv:

```
(my-project-venv)anto@~/d/m/myproject$ pip freeze | grep pytz
pytz==2014.4
(my-project-venv)anto@~/d/m/myproject$ python -c "import pytz; print pytz"
<module 'pytz' from '/home/anto/.virtualenvs/my-project-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.pyc'>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Currently using PyCharm 3.4.1, but as long as I can remember, I always had the issue.

Comment: What happens if you open a console in your project in PyCharm (Tools > Run Python Console...) and enter `import pytz`?

Comment: Everything goes fine, just like in shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because the virtualenv interpreter and interpreter that you've set for your pycharm project are not the same. Check your interpreter:

[image]

In my case, PyCharm was able to pick up that pytz is a module:

[image]

If the above failed, then try again after deleting the `.idea` folder in your project directory.

Comment: I wished it was that simple but I checked that already and the interp is properly set; I even can seen `pytz` in the interp's packages.  I drives me nuts.

Comment: @Anto Then, delete the .idea folder in your project directory, and reopen the directory with pycharm. That should do the trick.

Comment: Hell, it actually did :)  Probably worth an edit of your answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Anto Done. You can upvoate and accept the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue resolved by keeping my virtualenv outside my working project folder. Im not sure why it resolved the issue but it did miraculously.

Answer (score 0):

Pytz was installed on shell, however the pycharm was unable to detect the same, after installing the module in pycharm with following options, it started working for me...

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).