# Pip3 for Kubuntu 17.10 doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I searched much in net but I don't get what's going on with these two versions of Python available.
I did:
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

I have:

```
$ python3 -V 
$ Python 3.6.3
```

The I just did:

```
$ pip3 install pytz 
$ Collecting pytz 
$ Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/83/15f7833b70d3e067ca91467ca245bae0f6fe56ddc7451aa0dc5606b120f2/pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
$ Installing collected packages: pytzSuccessfully 
$ installed pytz-2018.4
```

And in Pycharm I see: 'No module named pytz'

Can someone help?

Comment: have you tried running `pip install pytz` instead of `pip3 install pytz`?

Comment: Yes,I've tried it and it Pycharm still doesn't see it. It can be a some proble with Pycharm configuration?

Comment: Try this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062269/pycharm-wont-find-pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062269/pycharm-wont-find-pytz)

Comment: Hi, I managed to managed to install pytz via Settings->Project Interpreter-> '+' to install pytz. It resulted that I didn't have pytz installed despite of the fact that I had done it via linux console. I'm not well familiar with Python so I don't know why it wasn't installed. Thank you for your help!